# How to programmatically check if a cell phone number is registered in the Telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I was wondering about what is the best way to know if a cell phone number has registered to the Telegram messenger or not?

Thanks.

Comment: if you are talking about the new bots api, it is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not familiar with python. but there is a way to do this:

As you know you can send a contact in telegram bot using its **phoneNumber** and a **firsName** (Doesn't need to be the real first name of the contact who owns that number).

After sending the contact to a chatID(no matter what chatID you choose, can be your own personal chat ID), you can look for its **UserID**.

> Now if the person exists in Telegram you will get a long number that
>   stands for his/her UserID or chatID but if not the long will be **0**.

In C# I used this piece of code to see whether a phone number exists in telegram or not and it worked very well.

```
string s = "+44....";    //the phone number
var req2 = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new SendContact(update.Message.Chat.Id, s, "Name"));
if(req2.Contact.UserId == 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The contact does not exist in Telegram");
}else
{
 Console.WriteLine("The contact exists in telegram with UserID:{0}",req2.Contact.UserId.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The number of contacts sent from same bot owner is limited. I didn't see actual limit value. My bots were blocked to send contacts for about a day after one of them sent about twenty contacts.

Comment: help me to find chatID where I can find it.or will it be token-id of my bot?

Comment: Hi Naser, do you know if this method still working now (Sep 1st 2020) ?

Comment: Hello, I haven't checked telegram bot api for a while. Let me check it and I'll reply to your question after a few hours.

Comment: @fredyfx I just finished over-viewing my old codes and what I noticed was that somehow the new telegram bot api manages to let you do this only for the users who already have sent at least one message to your bot (Or at least I think this way). Also, after a few number of tries, it gets blocked. I just wrote a simple console application in C# using NetTelegramBotApi NuGet package and I uploaded it to my gits. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/naser-sadeghi/4d36b8f7b89ad81e4866225f7d4da063). I thought it may help you.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi Bro, thanks a lot! I'm very grateful for your help. May God protects you and your family :D I would like to express my gratitude to you by sending you coffee, are you in those websites like buy me a coffee? Let me know! thanks a lot, your replay is giving me a chance to fix a hard situation that I'm living. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @fredyfx, I just figured that out, in case you're still wondering xD

Comment: hey @luvejo send a message on Telegram please! same username. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org/). However, you can with [python-telegram](http://python-telegram.readthedocs.io/).

In order to check whether a phone number is using Telegram or not, you need to add it as a contact.

```py
response = tg.call_method('importContacts', {
    'contacts': [
        {'phone_number': '+57 555 123 4567'},
    ]
})

response.wait()

user_ids = response.update['user_ids']

if user_ids[0] == 0:
    print('This contact is NOT using Telegram.')
else:
    print(f'¡This contact({user_ids[0]}) uses Telegram!')
```

I wrote a [tutorial](https://dev.to/luvejo/how-to-check-if-a-phone-number-is-on-telegram-using-tdlib-and-python-1kfl) on how to write the whole script, if you want to check it out.