# How can I check the database of phone numbers for the presence of the Telegram messenger?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have the numbers of the residents of my village - how can I check for the presence of installed Telegram on these numbers? I googled, but I couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718516/how-to-programmatically-check-if-a-cell-phone-number-is-registered-in-the-telegr) where the author created a nice [script](https://gist.github.com/naser-sadeghi/4d36b8f7b89ad81e4866225f7d4da063) to check if telegram is available for a phone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/) in python and a regular user account

```
import random
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

api_id = ...
api_hash = ' ... '
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    phone_number = '+ ... '
    result = await client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
        contacts=[types.InputPhoneContact(
            client_id=random.randrange(-2**63, 2**63),
            phone=phone_number,
            first_name='Some Name',
            last_name=''
        )]
    ))

    if len(result.users):
        print(f"{phone_number} has a telegram account")
        await client(functions.contacts.DeleteContactsRequest(result.users))
    else:
        print(f"couldn't find an account for {phone_number}")

client.start()
client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Here we are trying to add a new Contact (by using [`ImportContactsRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/import_contacts.html)) with the phone number and if that succeeds we get the users back inside the `users` field of the result ([`ImportedContacts`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/contacts/imported_contacts.html)) and an empty list otherwise. So we can just check the length of that field to determine whether the user has a telegram account or not.

And finally we remove the newly created contact at the end by executing [`DeleteContactsRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/delete_contacts.html).

Comment: Visit [this page](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/signing-in.html) for detailed instruction on authentication (to get `api_id` and `api_hash`)

Comment: Sorry for long reaction! Thx! That awersome!